# Django Aggregation in View

Tags: html, sql, django

I would like to show the result of the query from the database on my html view.
When I run my raw sql aggregate query in the Django shell, I get the result I'm looking for. But when I pass the data into my html from the view, it does not show any data.

My views.py and I also have the model imported

```
def officehome(request):
    """Renders the office home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    ordersrecieved = FbsOrderT.objects.count()
    return render(
        request,
        'app/officehome.html',
        {"ordersrecieved": ordersrecieved}
    )
```

this is in the html view

```
<ul class="list-group">
 <li class="list-group-item">
 <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">Orders Received <span {ordersrecieved}></span></h5>
  </li>
```

Would angular routing be a problem and not knowing when to execute the query.

Comment: Your span tag is missing a `>` and django template variables are enclosed in double curly braces, not single. You want `<span>{{ ordersreceived }}</span>`. If that doesn't solve it you might want to edit the question because right now it isn't clear what your problem is.

Comment: @Kevin I added the `>` and it still did not make a difference. The problem is that the data is not being shown in the view from the query.

Comment: And you utilized double brackets? Parameter passing into an HTML template will not function without them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
<h5 class="list-group-item-heading">Orders Received <span {ordersrecieved}></span></h5>
```

what you want is:

```
<h5 class="list-group-item-heading">Orders Received <span> {{ ordersrecieved }}</span></h5>
```

The way templating works is it converts {things which are in here to the python variable context} so if it is in the text of the html it will work if its an attribute of the span (as in `<span {gergerg}>`) then that might render but as nothing visible to the user. Also use `{{` `}}` rather than `{` unless you specified a custom templating parser.

Comment: Solved everything. Thanks